# teamcity how to handle configuration parameters which contains "%"

Tags: teamcity

for example, I need to pass a configuration paramters whose value is "abc%123", but when I encho the values, it is always "abc123", even I followed http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration
change the value to "abc%%123", the value echoed is still "abc123".
I use the teamcity 8.0.4. Does any body hear know how to solve this issue?

Comment: When having issues, especially with parameters, I create a new project with only one build step, generally a command line, so I can test this stuff out. It saves a lot of time and lets you hack on it pretty quickly. Use that with MrTaunus' answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enter the parameter value, you must escape the % with %%, i.e. abc%%123 instead of abc%123. Check out [Using the percent sign in TeamCity build scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389946/using-the-percent-sign-in-teamcity-build-scripts) for more in depth discussion.

Comment: @TuukkaHaapaniemi I have value with two percentage sign like 'abc%%123'. To escape in team city I added value like this 'abc%%%%123'. but teamcity is still resolving it as  'abc%123'.

Comment: @Anil It seems the escaping is dependent on the place where it's used. As per this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389946/using-the-percent-sign-in-teamcity-build-scripts I'd try with doubling the percentage signs, so in effect 8 signs: 'abc%%%%%%%%123'. Does that work for you? I don't have a TeamCity instance any longer to test this on, as I've moved to use Azure DevOps CI and CD pipelines.