# How to configure parameter value in team city with two % sign

Tags: teamcity

I need to setup string which is abc%%123 in team city parameter. I found this answer [teamcity how to handle configuration parameters which contains "%"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140999/teamcity-how-to-handle-configuration-parameters-which-contains) which suggest to escape % sign we should add one more % sign.
I added value in team city as 'abc%%%%123'. but teamcity still resolving string as 'abc%123'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use 4 percentage signs to esacape each percentage sign in string.