# Team City build step with Powershell Invoke-RestMethod fails if URI contains URL encoded value

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a build step in TeamCity which sends an HTTP request, like this:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Token", "%TOKEN%")
$uri = 'https://host/apps/branches/%BRANCH_NAME%/builds'
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='url' value='$uri']"
```

It works perfectly when `%BRANCH_NAME%` actually contains simple branch names, like `' master', 'beta', 'dev'`.

But it works not so good when `%BRANCH_NAME%` is `release%2F2019-DEC` (URL encoded value of `release/2019-DEC`)

I tried the same script on local Powershell, and it worked flawlessly, but when I run it as TeamCity build step I receive the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At C:\TeamCityBuildAgent4\temp\buildTmp\powershell7367326510068615884.ps1:5 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

##teamcity[setParameter name='url' value='https://host/app/branches/release%2F2019-DEC/']
```

I tried to escape the percent sign using the extra % sign as in [Using the percent sign in TeamCity build scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389946/using-the-percent-sign-in-teamcity-build-scripts), but unfortunately, it returns the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Imho you should convert this other way around. Instead of using extra % sign, you should convert `%2F` to `/`. But this is just a hunch. Also you could check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43135803/7225096

Comment: @Peska, thanks for your comment. 
The thing is that without URL encoding the target URI will be https://host/app/branches/release/2019-DEC/, which will return 404 as there is no such resource. 
If you curl https://host/app/branches/release%2F2019-DEC/ it would work, the tricky thing is that it doesn't work in TeamCity. 
Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

Seemingly issue was caused by the old version of PowerShell on Agent, which caused the behavior described in [Team City build step with Powershell Invoke-RestMethod fails if URI contains URL encoded value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283899/team-city-build-step-with-powershell-invoke-restmethod-fails-if-uri-contains-url)

That means that no extra percent signs are actually needed, we can URL encode value inside the script.

So the final version will look like:

```
function fixuri($uri){
  $UnEscapeDotsAndSlashes = 0x2000000;
  $SimpleUserSyntax = 0x20000;
  $type = $uri.GetType();
  $fieldInfo = $type.GetField("m_Syntax", ([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic));
  $uriParser = $fieldInfo.GetValue($uri);
  $typeUriParser = $uriParser.GetType().BaseType;
$fieldInfo = $typeUriParser.GetField("m_Flags", ([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::FlattenHierarchy));
$uriSyntaxFlags = $fieldInfo.GetValue($uriParser);
$uriSyntaxFlags = $uriSyntaxFlags -band (-bnot $UnEscapeDotsAndSlashes);
$uriSyntaxFlags = $uriSyntaxFlags -band (-bnot $SimpleUserSyntax);
$fieldInfo.SetValue($uriParser, $uriSyntaxFlags);
}
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("X-API-Token", "%TOKEN%")
$branch = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode('release/2019-DEC1')
$uri = New-Object System.Uri -ArgumentList ("https://host/apps/branches/$branch")
fixuri $uri
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
```

Special thanks to @Peska